# not able to run video from server on iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone

I have been trying to run a video from my app in iOS 4.1 but haven't met with success. Material everywhere give code for iOS 3.2 but not for the higher versions. Please help , I would be grateful to you. This is my code below:

```
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender { 

    NSString *urlString = 
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.itc.virginia.edu/network/videotest/when-sm.mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = 
      [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:urlString];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    [moviePlayer play];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewPlayer = 
      [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:urlString]; 

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewPlayer];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string will not convert itself to a URL automatically, you have to do it

```
   NSURL *urlString = 
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.itc.virginia.edu/network/videotest/when-sm.mov"];
```

also a moviePlayerViewController contains a moviePlayer so you don't need one separate

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewPlayer = 
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:urlString]; 

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewPlayer];
```

is all that is needed.

Comment: There is something wierd going on with your particular URL the mov is redirecting to something else which is confusing the player. It's an rtsp stream and not a plain movie. The iPhone doesn't really support rtsp streams.

Comment: Hi Walter , yes i agree the .mov URL isn't proper.I am not sure about video formats , i ll need to look at them. Thanks Walter, the code now works fine for mp4 format for ios 3.2 and 4.0. However mpg formats aren't supported.

Comment: The Apple documentation will tell you what is supported look at the MPMoviePlayerController reference. If you are wanting to support other formats, take a look at the FFMPEG/iPhone projects. They will require some extra coding on your end, but they let you support lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

u can simply play that vedio in webview by passing the url.by default it open in quick tym movie player 
thanks

Comment: Hi Vijay, i ran a mp4 format video in a webview for ios 3.2 it works good. But the same doesn't work for ios 4.1 or higher. Also mpg and .mov formats aren't being played. Plz post a sample working video if possible.
Thanks Vijay.